# jGrowl not working with MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to use [jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html) in an aspx page. But I encountered a problem that I couldn't solve.
When I use a regular aspx page the jGrowl is working fine. however when I use the page with a MasterPage the jGrowl is not working ,I got a javascript error saying $.jGrowl is not a function.

From Firebug Console, I can query $; $("a"); they return objects. Which means jquery is loaded, but $.jGrowl("hello world"); return "$.jGrowl is not a function."

Here is the sample code I'm using

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="growl.aspx.vb" Inherits="growl"
MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.Master" Title="growl" %>
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="maincontent1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
$(document).ready(function() { $('#demo12').click(function() { $.jGrowl("Growl Notification");
}); });
<button id="demo12" type="reset" onclick="$.jGrowl('Hello WORLD');">
    DEMO</button>
```

The master page contains an Asp:ScriptManager.

Any help is very appreciate it.

Thanks,

Comment: Even without loading jQuery, Firebug will still have "$" and "$$" defined, because they define it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was a literal in the MasterPage that is set in the page_Load to include the javascript library. When I removed  it it works fine.

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `jQuery.noConflict()` and `jQuery.jGrowl()` to see if there is a conflict with the $ function between jQuery and the Microsoft javascript libraries?

Comment: I tried it but still getting TypeError: jQuery.jGrowl is not a function

Comment: I don't know if this is part of the problem, but $('#demo12') won't work with a master page due to the name mangling.  You'll need to use $('[id$=demo12]') -- i.e., find the element whose id ends with demo12.

Answer (score 0):

Might be obvious, but can you check if you are correctly referencing the library? You might have the wrong path.

Comment: it is the right library , I checked the script loaded using Firebug.